# Help solving a system (kinda) with modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

If I have

1) $3x \equiv5$ mod $11$

2) $2y \equiv 7$ mod $11$

then $x+y$ is congruent with what mod $11$.

I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring this one out. This is how I've approached it:

$1) \Rightarrow \frac{3x-5}{11} = k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$2) \Rightarrow \frac{2x-7}{11} = j$ for some $j \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then I need to solve

3) $\frac{x + y-z}{11} = h$.

That is, I need to find some integer $z$ such that for some combination of integers $(j, k, h)$, 3) holds.
Is this true? Whether or not it's true, is this an efficient way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply first equation with 4 you get $x \equiv -2$ (mod $11$) and

if you multiply second equation with 6 you get $y \equiv -2$ (mod $11$)

so $x+y \equiv 7$ (mod $11$).

Comment: I see; so what I wrote out was true, but it was also totally the wrong way to approach the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$3x \equiv-6 \mod 11$$

$$2y \equiv -4 \mod 11$$

Then you can reduce them by $3$ and $2$ as they are relatively prime with 11

$$x \equiv-2 \mod 11$$

$$y \equiv -2 \mod 11$$

$$x+y \equiv -4 \mod 11$$

$$x+y \equiv 7 \mod 11$$

$$x+y=11n+7$$

Answer (score 1):

$3x \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$, means (everything times $2$):
$6x \equiv 10 \pmod{11}$.

$2y \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$ means (everything times $3$):
$6y \equiv 21 \equiv 10 \pmod{11}$.

Then $6(x+y) \equiv 20 \equiv 9 \pmod{11}$. Multiply both sides by $6^{-1} \pmod{11}$, which is $2$, hence $x+y \equiv 18 \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$